# Codename on app store build iTuneswork size

Tags: codenameone

I have run into an issue while submitting the app to the app store.  I really thought that the iTuneswork file is the icon file which is, but the size of the file 512x512 which is required on the codenameone project.

The app store is required to upload 1024x1024 icon.  Just wondering why codnename app is only allowing 512x512 when building creating the build.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use 1024x1024 it will work too. This is undocumented as it's not necessary for the app itself.